Cannot change colors of widgets
I want to create an outline around a selected area of a treeview when the mouse button is clicked and dragged. I want to do this by creating a frame (or canvas with a rectangle drawn in it) on top of the treeview. This frame (or canvas) will have a specific bg color that I'll make invisible using wm_attribute.
The placement of the widget on top of the treeview works as expected, but I can't set the color of the widgets' background; it always stays white. Does anybody know what causes this and how to fix it?
Below is the code of the class that shows the treeview and an interface to choose the table, which are retrieved from a database. The area where the problem occurs is in the functions on_click() and on_drag().
class ShowDatabaseFrame():
    """Creates a treeview to show database results in"""
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        output_frame = self.master.notebook_list[get_active_tab_index(self.master)]["output_frame"]
        self.output_table_name = [None, None]    #Name of the shown table [old, new]

        #region Create widgets
        self.master_frame = tb.Frame(output_frame)
        self.output_help_frame = tb.Frame(self.master_frame)
        self.output_table = tb.Treeview(self.output_help_frame,
                                         columns=(0),
                                         show='headings',
                                         selectmode='extended')
        self.output_scroll_y = tb.Scrollbar(self.output_help_frame,
                                             orient="vertical",
                                             command=self.output_table.yview)
        self.output_scroll_x = tb.Scrollbar(self.master_frame,
                                             orient="horizontal",
                                             command=self.output_table.xview)
        #endregion

        #region Place widgets
        self.master_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.output_help_frame.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        self.output_table.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
        self.output_scroll_y.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.output_scroll_x.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        #endregion

        #region Initialize treeview table
        self.output_table.heading(0, text="No table selected")
        self.output_table.insert("", "end", values=[""], iid="cond_row")
        self.output_table.configure(yscrollcommand=self.output_scroll_y.set,
                                    xscrollcommand=self.output_scroll_x.set)
        #endregion

        #Create key bindings
        self.output_table.bind("<Double-1>", self._on_double_click)
        self.output_table.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_click)
        self.output_table.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.on_drag)
        self.output_table.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_release)

    def _on_double_click(self, event):
        #Get column and its index
        col_clicked = self.output_table.identify_column(event.x)
        col_index = int(col_clicked[1:])-1

        #Get ID
        selected_iid = self.output_table.focus()

        #Create entry if necessary
        if selected_iid == "cond_row":
            #Get selected values
            selected_values = self.output_table.item(selected_iid)

            #Get dimension and create ntry
            box_dim = self.output_table.bbox(selected_iid, col_clicked)
            self.edit_entry = tb.Entry(self.master_frame)

            #Write variables to the widget to use for later
            self.edit_entry.edit_col_index = col_index
            self.edit_entry.edit_item_iid = selected_iid

            #Bind events
            self.edit_entry.bind("<FocusOut>", self._on_focus_out)
            self.edit_entry.bind("<Return>", self._on_entry)

            #Setup of the entry
            self.edit_entry.place(x=box_dim[0], y=box_dim[1], w=box_dim[2], h=box_dim[3])
            self.edit_entry.insert(0, selected_values.get("values")[col_index])
            self.edit_entry.select_range(0, tk.END)
            self.edit_entry.focus()

    def on_click(self,event):
        """Gets starting position of the selection"""
        #Get ID, column and its index
        col = self.output_table.identify_column(event.x)
        row = self.output_table.identify_row(event.y)

        #Get dimension and create entry
        if self.output_table.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == "cell":
            self.dim_start = self.output_table.bbox(row, col)
            """
            self.outline_canvas = tk.Canvas(self.output_help_frame,
                                            width=self.output_table.winfo_width(),
                                            height=self.output_table.winfo_height(),
                                            bg="green")
            self.outline_canvas.grid_propagate()
            self.outline_canvas.place(x=0,
                                      y=0)#+self.output_table.winfo_rooty())
            self.outline_rectangle = self.outline_canvas.create_rectangle(
                self.dim_start[0],
                self.dim_start[1],
                self.dim_start[0]+self.dim_start[2],
                self.dim_start[1]+self.dim_start[3]
                )
            """
            self.outline = tk.Frame(self.output_table,
                                    width=self.dim_start[2],
                                    height=self.dim_start[3],
                                    bg="#00FF00")
            self.outline.grid_propagate()
            self.outline.place(x=self.dim_start[0],#+self.output_table.winfo_rootx(),
                               y=self.dim_start[1])#+self.output_table.winfo_rooty())

    def on_drag(self,event):
        """Adjusts the size of the selection"""
        #Get ID, column and its index
        col = self.output_table.identify_column(event.x)
        row = self.output_table.identify_row(event.y)

        #Get dimension and create entry
        if self.output_table.identify_region(event.x, event.y) == "cell":
            """
            dim_curr = self.output_table.bbox(row, col)
            self.outline_canvas.coords(self.outline_rectangle,
                                       self.dim_start[0],
                                       self.dim_start[1],
                                       dim_curr[0]+dim_curr[2]-self.dim_start[0],
                                       dim_curr[1]+dim_curr[3]-self.dim_start[1])
            """
            dim_curr = self.output_table.bbox(row, col)
            self.outline.config(width=dim_curr[2]+(dim_curr[0]-self.dim_start[0]),
                                height=dim_curr[3]+(dim_curr[1]-self.dim_start[1]))

    def on_release(self,event):
        """Sets the outline"""
        #Get ID, column and its index
        self.select_start_x = self.output_table.identify_column(event.x)
        self.select_start_y = self.output_table.identify_row(event.y)

    def _on_focus_out(self, event):
        event.widget.destroy()

    def _on_entry(self, event):
        #Get values
        new_text = event.widget.get()
        selected_iid = event.widget.edit_item_iid
        col_index = event.widget.edit_col_index

        #Take the values tuple, change the one value and use the new tuple in the table
        current_values = self.output_table.item(selected_iid).get("values")
        current_values[col_index] = new_text
        self.output_table.item(selected_iid, values=current_values)

        #destroy entry
        event.widget.destroy()

        #Update table
        self.master.fun_sql_query_maker()

I tried using a canvas widget and a frame widget and different background colors. I've read online there's a bug when using the ttk aqua theme on apple, but use windows and I use mostly ttkbootstrap widgets (the widget created on top of the treeview is a tk widget)
